# Problem With Views Inside of TabBars (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITableView that I am placing inside a TabView. I am trying to put a "spinner" and a label in the center of the TableView. When I view I try to view it inside the TabBar, I do not see the spinner or label. When I view this nib by itself, I see the spinner and TabBar.

There seems to be something about views / tabbars that I am not getting...

Comment: you mean you are trying to place "spinner" and "label" over uitableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the UILabel and UIActivity indicator on the tableview in the nib, I suggest you add them to the view containing the tableview by adding them in viewDidLoad or an appropriate method of your view controller.
e.g.

```
UIActivityIndicator activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[activityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(160,200)];
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

Similarly you can add the label and position it in the view.

You can then add

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

and

```
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

wherever you want the spinner to start or stop animating. I am not sure what you want to do with the label. If its to display a loading message, you can make the label hidden or visible as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to play with the threads a bit, but this is working.

Answer (score 0):

if you are putting Label On the UITableView than chances are there that TableView will be overlapped on your label and spinner...